# asyncio - wait for each task in a dynamic list to finish or be cancelled

Tags: python, python-3.x, asynchronous, async-await, python-asyncio

I have a list of asyncio tasks: `[task1, task2, task3]`. And each task can append more tasks to this list, e.g., `task3` might append `task4`.

How can I wait for all tasks in this dynamic list to finish or be cancelled?

I tried `await asyncio.gather(*[task1, task2, task3])`, but it doesn't wait for tasks created by `task1`, `task2` or `task3`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a loop to wait for as long as there are unfinished tasks:

```
# create a list to hold the tasks
task_list = []

# you can pass task_list to coroutines that need to submit
# additional tasks
task_list.extend([task1, coro1(arg1, task_list), coro2(arg2, task_list)])

while task_list:
    old_cnt = len(task_list)
    await asyncio.gather(*task_list)
    # we've finished the old set of tasks, but keep looping as long
    # as some coroutines keep adding new ones
    del task_list[:old_cnt]
```

Contents of `task_list` don't need to be just actual `asyncio.Task` instances, the list can also contain coroutine objects or anything else that is awaitable. You can pass `task_list` to the coroutines that need to append more tasks to the list. Once no new tasks have been added, the task list will remain empty after the call to `gather`, and the loop will terminate.