# Python asyncio, aiohttp: dynamically updating tasks loop should work until particular condition

Tags: python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have simple script for work with api. I create `number_of_user` users. I go thru loop, create random user `create_random_user()`, for every user I create task and append task to loop. Task for user creation `async def fetch_user_create` after getting response create another task for user log in `async def fetch_user_log` and add it to all tasks. My question: how can I wait until, for example, `len(tasks_user) == 2 * number_of_user`.

I tried to place await asyncio.sleep(1) - it's work but depends of   number_of_user.

**Target: wait until condition** Is it possible? Or what I did wrong?

```
async def fetch_user_log(session, data_user):
    async with session.post(url_user_login, data=data_user) as response:

async def fetch_user_create(session, data_user, tasks_user_create):
    async with session.post(url_user_create, data=data_user) as response:
        task2 = asyncio.ensure_future(fetch_user_log(session, data_user))
        tasks_user.append(task2)
        #await asyncio.sleep(1)
        await response.read()
        
        #await asyncio.gather(*tasks_user) - tried

async def run():
    tasks_user = []
    async with ClientSession() as session:
        for i in range(number_of_user):
            data_user = create_random_user()
            task = asyncio.ensure_future(fetch_user_create(session, data_user, tasks_user_create))
            tasks_user.append(task)
        await asyncio.wait(tasks_user)
        #await asyncio.gather(*tasks_user) - tried

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
future = asyncio.ensure_future(run())
loop.run_until_complete(future)
```

Comment: Please be more specific about which deprecated API you skipped reading about. A misunderstanding might lurk in that area.

Comment: I removed unnecessary information from my question It wasn't matter. I started working with asyncio and may have written the wrong information.My target is: force await until condition. I want to add extra tasks while script running, but get `Server disconnected`. If I place `await asyncio.sleep(1)` it works ok, but if I increase `number_of_user` I should increase `asyncio.sleep(1)`. I want to get result with no `asyncio.sleep(1)`.

Comment: why you block here?

Comment: i think you need asincio.gather in loop here

Comment: I tried to place `await asyncio.gather(*tasks_user)` in code (I updated topic with # sign) . It works but I have endless loop

Comment: I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61208300/asyncio-wait-for-each-task-in-a-dynamic-list-to-finish-or-be-cancelled). It works for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wait until condition can be implemented with asyncio.Condition:

```
import asyncio

async def test_wait_for(cond, tasks):
    print(".")
    async with cond:
        await cond.wait_for(lambda: (len(tasks)>3))
    print("!")

async def test_add_task(cond, tasks):
    for i in range(6):
        print(i)
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
        async with cond:
            tasks.append(i)
            cond.notify_all()

async def run():
    cond = asyncio.Condition()
    tasks = []
    asyncio.ensure_future(test_wait_for(cond, tasks))
    await test_add_task(cond, tasks)
    


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
future = asyncio.ensure_future(run())
loop.run_until_complete(future)
```

Condition is Event+Lock. Event sent with `notify_all` unlocks all `wait` and `wait_for` coroutines. Lock here also locks tasks array.

Also it can be implemented with asyncio.Event if you move condition to task that send notify.

Comment: [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html) Lock, Event, Condition Deprecated since version 3.8, will be removed in version 3.10: The loop parameter.

Comment: @koko, again... read line to the end: `Deprecated since version 3.8, will be removed in version 3.10: The loop parameter.` --- loop parameter deprecated, not class