# How to append additional tasks in asyncio.as_completed(task_list)

Tags: python, python-asyncio

I have a coroutine function to fetch results from a URL:

```
async def create_task_form_url(aio_session, form_url: str) -> [Future]:
    loop = get_running_loop()
    task = loop.create_task(async_get_results(form_url, aio_session))
    return task
```

I'm trying to create the initial task, and use `as_completed` to get the result. Along the way, *depending on some logic* I would want to append to the `tasks` list so that `as_completed` can fetch the result as well.

This is where my problem comes in, where the `for` loop closes out before the 2nd task completes. How can I do this correctly?

```
tasks = [await create_task_form_url(self.aio_session, form_url)]

print(len(tasks))

for each_task in as_completed(tasks):
    print(await each_task)
    tasks.append(await create_task_form_url(self.aio_session, form_url))
    print(len(tasks))
```

Output:

```
1
# Task 1 result is printed.
2  # So we know that the tasks.append works. But the result was never retrieved.
Error msg: Task was destroyed but it is pending!
```

Comment: Do you strictly want to get the result of the first task first, or do you want to get the result of whichever task (first or second) finishes first?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [asyncio - wait for each task in a dynamic list to finish or be cancelled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61208300/asyncio-wait-for-each-task-in-a-dynamic-list-to-finish-or-be-cancelled)

Comment: However, in your example code it seems that adding the second task does not actually depend on some condition, but you simply start it after the first task has finished.

Answer (score 2):

Use `asyncio.wait` instead - https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#asyncio.wait

After your desired iteration (it can also accept a timeout), it returns 2 sets: one with the completed tasks, and another with those still pending. You can add new tasks to the "pending" ones, and iterate again:

```
async def main():
    tasks = {await create_task_form_url(self.aio_session, form_url), }

    print(len(tasks))
    
    while tasks:
        done, pending = asyncio.wait(tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_COMPLETED)

        for each_task in done:
            print(await each_task.result())
        tasks = pending
        ...
        if <condition_to_add_new_task>:
            tasks.add(await create_task_form_url(self.aio_session, form_url))
        print(len(tasks))
        
asyncio.run(main())
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need `as_completed` for your use case. In your example program you already `await`s for all tasks to complete (at the first line inside the list comprehension), thus `as_completed` won't perform anything useful here.

If you do not need the results as they are completed you can `await` for some of them and then schedule other tasks following that. If you need concurrent execution, you may use `asyncio.gather()`.

However, iff you are using Python 3.11 you can use a [`TaskGroup`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-task.html#task-groups) to manage concurrent tasks and schedule new ones as they go.

Inside the task group `async-with` context manager you can create as many concurrent requests as you want. Then, you can wait for completion of some of them using the task handles you get when submitting a task to the group. finally you can schedule other tasks to the task group depending on the output of the previous tasks.

Here is an example:

```py
import asyncio


async def get_hello() -> str:
    await asyncio.sleep(1.0)
    return "Hello"


async def get_comma() -> str:
    await asyncio.sleep(1.0)
    return ", "


async def get_world() -> str:
    await asyncio.sleep(1.0)
    return "world!"


async def main():
    async with asyncio.TaskGroup() as tg:
        # Launch two concurrent tasks.
        tasks = [
            tg.create_task(get_hello()),
            tg.create_task(get_comma()),
        ]

        # Wait for the completion of some of them and get the value.
        first_word = await tasks[0]

        # Launch other tasks depending on the value.
        if first_word == "Hello":
            task = tg.create_task(get_world())
        else:
            raise ValueError("first word was not 'Hello'")

    # All submitted tasks are guaranted completed after the
    # task group closing, i.e. after the `async-with` statement.
    comma = await tasks[1]
    second_word = await task

    print(first_word, comma, second_word, sep="")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    asyncio.run(main())
```

Alternatively you can use the solution given by @jsbuino which uses `wait()` or you could use queues (`asyncio.Queue`).